# Is PDF.js compatible with older browsers?

Tags: javascript, pdf

So I'm trying to embed a pdf on a page. I'm getting the pdf from a webservice and the service is returning the pdf as a byte array using json. I'm not sure what the best way to embed the pdf is considering I need to make sure it's pretty compatible with all browsers.

What is the **right** way to do this? What I am doing right now is taking the byte array and converting it to base64 then trying to embed it in the browser, however it's not working properly. I feel like this is a good approach however, my embeded pdf isn't compatible with IE for some reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: To answer the question in the title: [kinda](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#what-browsers-are-supported)

Comment: Some older browsers require the user to have a plugin installed for the browser to display a pdf file. So you aren't going to be able to embed a pdf on every broswer

Comment: @PatrickEvans So what's the best way to tackle this in your opinion?

Comment: IE cannot work with long base64 URLs -- don't even try it to convert to base64, just feed it to the PDF.js. You out of luck with IE8 and below browsers, so you have to return valid PDF stream from the server to make it work there.